# jquery slideUp() to the left side

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i will create a weekly calendar.
When i switch the week, i would like to slide the old week to left or right to get the new content.
Can anybody help me?
At the moment i have no good idea to implement this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To slide to the left for example instead of [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) you can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) directly, like this:

```
$(".oldweek").animate({ width: 0 });
//or...
$(".oldweek").animate({ width: "toggle" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Jquery UI slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide):

```
$("#calender").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Or, if you don't want to include Jquery UI, I would suggest to do something like this:

html

```
<div id="calendar-wrapper">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
calendar-wrapper { overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
calendar { 
position:absolute; 
width:100px; 
height:100px; 
top:0;
left:-100px;
}
```

js (jquery)

```
//to show
$("#calender").animate({"left":"0px"}, 1000);

//to hide
$("#calender").animate({"left":"-" + $("#calender").width() + "px"}, 1000);
```

You can also use classes instead of specifying the left position in js and then animate that.

I've also seen people animate {"width":"toggle"} but i find that laggy. try it if you want to.

As you can see there are many solutions for what you require. good luck!!

Comment: I tried using `animate({"displat":"none"}, 1000)`, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery Cycle plugin to get the desired output... if  u having knowledge of jQuery...

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/